# Cannot find all match value in nested list Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Hey I have list i want to find all matching item. I tried some code but it not working all finding items. I need to do in efficient way. I guess my below code returns first matching item.

**Group**

```
data class Group(
    val key: Int,
    val value: MutableList<GroupValue?>
)
```

**GroupValue**

```
data class GroupValue(
    val isRead: Boolean? = null,
    val id: String? = null
)
```

**Main.kt**

```
fun main() {
    val value = listOf(
        Group(0, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "1"))),
        Group(1, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "2"))),
        Group(2, mutableListOf(GroupValue(false, "3"))),
        Group(3, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "4"))),
        Group(4, mutableListOf(GroupValue(false, "5"))),
        Group(5, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "6"))),
        Group(6, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "7"), GroupValue(false, "8"))),
        Group(7, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "9"), GroupValue(false, "10"))),
        Group(8, mutableListOf(GroupValue(false, "11"), GroupValue(false, "12"), GroupValue(false, "13"))),
        Group(9, mutableListOf(GroupValue(false, "14"), GroupValue(true, "15"))),
        Group(10, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "16")))
    )

    val list = value.slice(2..9)
    var groupValue: GroupValue? = null
    list.forEach { messageGroup ->
        groupValue = messageGroup.value.find { it?.isRead == false }
        if (groupValue != null) {
            println(groupValue)
        }
    }
}
```

**Output getting through above code**

```
GroupValue(isRead=false, id=3)
GroupValue(isRead=false, id=5)
GroupValue(isRead=false, id=8)
GroupValue(isRead=false, id=10)
GroupValue(isRead=false, id=11)
GroupValue(isRead=false, id=14)
```

**Expected output**

```
GroupValue(isRead=false, id=3)
GroupValue(isRead=false, id=5)
GroupValue(isRead=false, id=8)
GroupValue(isRead=false, id=10)
GroupValue(isRead=false, id=11)
GroupValue(isRead=false, id=12)
GroupValue(isRead=false, id=13)
GroupValue(isRead=false, id=14)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `filter()` instead of `find()` (`find()` gets you only a single object but you want multiple) as follows:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val value = listOf(
        Group(0, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "1"))),
        Group(1, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "2"))),
        Group(2, mutableListOf(GroupValue(false, "3"))),
        Group(3, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "4"))),
        Group(4, mutableListOf(GroupValue(false, "5"))),
        Group(5, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "6"))),
        Group(6, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "7"), GroupValue(false, "8"))),
        Group(7, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "9"), GroupValue(false, "10"))),
        Group(8, mutableListOf(GroupValue(false, "11"), GroupValue(false, "12"), GroupValue(false, "13"))),
        Group(9, mutableListOf(GroupValue(false, "14"), GroupValue(true, "15"))),
        Group(10, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "16")))
    )

    val list = value.slice(2..9)
    list.forEach { messageGroup ->
        val groupValues = messageGroup.value.filter { it?.isRead == false }
        if (groupValues.isNotEmpty()) {
            println(groupValues)
        }
    }
}
```

This will give you the following output:

```
[GroupValue(isRead=false, id=3)]
[GroupValue(isRead=false, id=5)]
[GroupValue(isRead=false, id=8)]
[GroupValue(isRead=false, id=10)]
[GroupValue(isRead=false, id=11), GroupValue(isRead=false, id=12), GroupValue(isRead=false, id=13)]
[GroupValue(isRead=false, id=14)]
```

In order to get what you want you need to change the code a bit more to map each `Group` object to a list of `GroupValue` and then flatten the list of lists. Check the following code:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val value = listOf(
        Group(0, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "1"))),
        Group(1, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "2"))),
        Group(2, mutableListOf(GroupValue(false, "3"))),
        Group(3, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "4"))),
        Group(4, mutableListOf(GroupValue(false, "5"))),
        Group(5, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "6"))),
        Group(6, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "7"), GroupValue(false, "8"))),
        Group(7, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "9"), GroupValue(false, "10"))),
        Group(8, mutableListOf(GroupValue(false, "11"), GroupValue(false, "12"), GroupValue(false, "13"))),
        Group(9, mutableListOf(GroupValue(false, "14"), GroupValue(true, "15"))),
        Group(10, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "16")))
    )

    val list = value.slice(2..9)
    list.map { messageGroup -> messageGroup.value.filter { it?.isRead == false } }
        .flatten()
        .forEach { println(it) }
}
```

Comment: great answer @JoãoDias. Thanks a million

Comment: one question @JoãoDias is **first** example is more efficient than **second** example because we are using `flatten()` and `forEach` ?

Comment: i want to do in efficient way like good performances, memory management etc.

Comment: Yes, it might be slightly more efficient but I don't think the difference would be that great. Keep in mind that sometimes we tend to focus too much on performance and less on the software quality and usefulness. That is why some people say that "premature optimization is the root of all evil". Of course this depends on the context. If you are working on a highly critical or memory-constricted environment (let's say NASA software), then performance and optimizations are very important, but this is not usually the case and the small gains are most likely irrelevant.

Comment: ok great!! Thanks a million once again